# Can't change font size for GD imagestring()

Tags: php, image

I'm trying to follow  [this example](http://designgala.com/how-to-add-text-in-an-image/)  to generate an image with dynamic text.

I wanted to change the size of the font, I put even 100 instead of 4, but it still appears same as before.

I'm not very good at PHP. Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Here's [an example](http://sushi.usask.ca/passimagemodels/levAclue1.png) how small it appears :(

Here's my example code -

```
       $font = 'arial.ttf'; //FONT SIZE

       $width = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($string) ;
       $height = imagefontheight($font) ;
       $im = imagecreatefrompng($imageO);

       $x = imagesx($im) / 2;   //PLACEMENT CENTERISH – X
       $y = imagesy($im) / 2;   //PLACEMENT CENTERISH – Y

      // $backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 255, 255, 255);

       $transparency = 25;
       imagesavealpha($im, true);
       $background = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, background_r, background_g, background_b, $transparency);

       $textColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0,0,0);
       imagestring ($im, $font, $x, $y, $string, $textColor);
       imagepng($im,$imageN[$k]);
       $w = imagesx($im);
       $h = imagesy($im);
```

Thanks

### ADDED LATER

Ok now here it is what I have done but as a result, no text is visible in the callout box.

```
       $font = 'arial.ttf'; //YOUR FONT SIZE

       $im = imagecreatefrompng($imageO);
       $string = "My Text";
       $imageN ="NewImage.png";

       $transparency = 25;
       imagesavealpha($im, true);
       $background = imagecolorallocatealpha($im, background_r, background_g, background_b, $transparency);

       $textColor = imagecolorallocate ($im, 0,0,0);
       //imagestring ($im, 5, $x, $y, $string, $textColor);
       imagettftext($im, 36, 0, 10, 20, $textColor, $font, $string);
       imagepng($im,$imageN);
```

Comment: Is it okay to omit `imagecolordeallocate` and `imagedestroy` like stuffs? They don't seem to effect the script?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't put 100 - http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php

Only 1-5 (by default)

**UPDATE**

To be able fully control the font size you might want to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Example (from the same site):

```
<?php
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 30);

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 128, 128, 128);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 399, 29, $white);

// The text to draw
$text = 'Testing...';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = 'arial.ttf';

// Add some shadow to the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 11, 21, $grey, $font, $text);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: The you have to use http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php In that function you can define font height in pixels. Look at the examples below for usage

Comment: Should I use it instead of imagestring?

Comment: It definitely gives you more control over font size and that's what you want. So yes.

Comment: Thanks Zoltan.. But seems like the text is not appearing. You can have a look in my example.

Comment: Can't I give font as a null or blank?

Comment: @RakeshOstwal why don't you just try? :)

Comment: How can i change font family?

Comment: @151291 array imagettftext ( resource $image , float $size , float $angle , int $x , int $y , int $color , **string $fontfile** , string $text ) - you need to include a fontfile that you wish to use

Answer (score 2):

Anybody like thinking outside the box? Yeah me too.

So if you have to use PHP's `imagestring` rather than `imagettftext` there is an way to create text sizes larger than the standard 1-5 range, and it requires you to create the text as size A and then resize the image you've created the text on to be larger. How large depends on how big you want the text.

So let's walk through it...

:1. Create blank pngs just to put our text onto. We also need a final image to compile things to. These could use `imagecreatetruecolor` for transparent backgrounds.

```
$ImageText1Small = imagecreate( 148, 16 );
$ImageText1Large = imagecreate( 148, 16 );
$ImageText2Small = imagecreate( 308, 40 );
$ImageText2Large = imagecreate( 308, 40 );
$ImageFinal = imagecreate( 500, 100 );
```

:2. Sort the background and text colour for our text images. Black and white. How original.

```
$backgroundColor1 = imagecolorallocate($ImageText1Small, 255,255,255);
$textColor1 = imagecolorallocate($ImageText1Small, 0,0,0);

$backgroundColor2 = imagecolorallocate($ImageText2Small, 255,255,255);
$textColor2 = imagecolorallocate($ImageText2Small, 0,0,0);
```

:3. We need text. Add it.

```
imagestring( $ImageText1Small, 1, 1, 0, 'Stack Overflow',  $textColor1 );
imagestring( $ImageText2Small, 5, 1, 0, 'Harry Harry Harry',  $textColor2 );
```

:4. This is the clever bit. Resize the smaller text images to make them larger than the max 5 font.

```
imagecopyresampled($ImageText1Large, $ImageText1Small, 0, 0, 0, 0, 148, 16, 74, 8);
imagecopyresampled($ImageText2Large, $ImageText2Small, 0, 0, 0, 0, 308, 40, 154, 20);
```

:5. Here I do some rotation, but obviously that's optional.

```
$ImageText1Large = imagerotate ( $ImageText1Large, 20, $backgroundColor1 );
$ImageText2Large = imagerotate ( $ImageText2Large, -5, $backgroundColor2 );
```

:6. Get dimensions of our newly rotated images. Again this is optional if you rotate.

```
$ImageText1W = imagesx($ImageText1Large);
$ImageText1H = imagesy($ImageText1Large);

$ImageText2W = imagesx($ImageText2Large);
$ImageText2H = imagesy($ImageText2Large);
```

:7. Stick the text image layers on to the final image:

```
imagecopymerge($ImageFinal, $ImageText1Large, 350, 20, 0, 0, $ImageText1W, $ImageText1H, 100);
imagecopymerge($ImageFinal, $ImageText2Large, 20, 20, 0, 0, $ImageText2W, $ImageText2H, 100);
```

:4. Print it out, or save it:

```
header( 'Content-type: image/png' );
imagepng($ImageFinal, 0);
```

:5. Clean up after ourselves:

```
imagecolordeallocate( $ImageText1Small, $textColor1 );
imagecolordeallocate( $ImageText1Small, $backgroundColor1 );
imagecolordeallocate( $ImageText1Large, $textColor2 );
imagecolordeallocate( $ImageText1Large, $backgroundColor2 );
imagedestroy($ImageText1); 
imagedestroy($ImageText2);
imagedestroy($ImageFinal);
```

Obviously you can play around with:
 * Starting image size
 * Starting font (1-5)
 * Rotation
 * Scaling up further
 * Background colours
 * Transparent backgrounds
 * Positioning
 * `imagepng` compression level

The whole script, imperfect, but functional is here:

```
$ImageText1Small = imagecreate( 148, 16 );
$ImageText1Large = imagecreate( 148, 16 );
$ImageText2Small = imagecreate( 308, 40 );
$ImageText2Large = imagecreate( 308, 40 );
$ImageFinal = imagecreate( 500, 100 );

$backgroundColor1 = imagecolorallocate($ImageText1Small, 255,255,255);
$textColor1 = imagecolorallocate($ImageText1Small, 0,0,0);

$backgroundColor2 = imagecolorallocate($ImageText2Small, 255,255,255);
$textColor2 = imagecolorallocate($ImageText2Small, 0,0,0);

imagestring( $ImageText1Small, 1, 1, 0, 'Stack Overflow',  $textColor1 );
imagestring( $ImageText2Small, 5, 1, 0, 'Harry Harry Harry',  $textColor2 );

imagecopyresampled($ImageText1Large, $ImageText1Small, 0, 0, 0, 0, 148, 16, 74, 8);
imagecopyresampled($ImageText2Large, $ImageText2Small, 0, 0, 0, 0, 308, 40, 154, 20);

$ImageText1Large = imagerotate ( $ImageText1Large, 20, $backgroundColor1 );
$ImageText2Large = imagerotate ( $ImageText2Large, -5, $backgroundColor2 );

$ImageText1W = imagesx($ImageText1Large);
$ImageText1H = imagesy($ImageText1Large);

$ImageText2W = imagesx($ImageText2Large);
$ImageText2H = imagesy($ImageText2Large);

imagecopymerge($ImageFinal, $ImageText1Large, 350, 20, 0, 0, $ImageText1W, $ImageText1H, 100);
imagecopymerge($ImageFinal, $ImageText2Large, 20, 20, 0, 0, $ImageText2W, $ImageText2H, 100);

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng($ImageFinal);

imagecolordeallocate( $ImageText1, $textColor1 );
imagecolordeallocate( $ImageText2, $textColor2 );
imagedestroy($ImageText1); 
imagedestroy($ImageText2);
```

Comment: Finally A different solution. - Thanks, Any idea about getting normal looking fonts?

Comment: Sadly font choice is *very* limited with this method. If you want to get *really* clever I guess you could create a tiny image of each letter and number in a font you like and then piece them together.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use imagettftext if you want to write bigger text in any font of your choosing.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Answer (score 0):

Many suggestions, but no solutions...

Here's a working solution.
The trick is to use **imagettftext()** for this.
It lets you choose any truetype font in any size.

On an existing image use the following code:

```
<?php
  $txt = 'This is the text overlay';

  header('Content-type: image/png');

  $image = ImageCreateFromJPEG('existingimage.jpg'); // path to the existing image
  $color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); // black
  $font = 'fontname.ttf'; // path to font
  imagettftext($image, 14, 0, 395, 85, $color, $font, $txt );

  imagepng($image); // png gets better font results than jpg
  imagedestroy($image);
?>
```

This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the font style of a sting can be done either with imagettftext() function or imageloadfont() . With both you can change the font style but with imageloadfont()  you are just loading well defined binary font file, and in this case you have no control over the exact size of the font, can’t customize it. You can NOT load also true type font files they should be GDF Files. 
Using the imagettftext() function you have full control over the font style, size, font-family etc.  in this case you should use true type font files directly by allocating the file on your computer/server. 
Here are 2 examples with both functions: 
Example with captcha functionality using imageloadfont():

//Set the image width and height 
    $width = 150; 
    $height = 30;

```
//Create the image resource 
$image = ImageCreate($width, $height);  

//We are making three colors, white, black and gray 
$white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255); 
$black = ImageColorAllocate($image, 46, 29, 29); 
$grey = ImageColorAllocate($image, 204, 204, 204); 

//Make the background black 
ImageFill($image, 0, 0, $black); 

$font = imageloadfont('04b.gdf');

$text='Testing'; 
//Add randomly generated string in white to the image
ImageString($image, $font, 20, 3, $text, $white);

ImageRectangle($image,0,0,$width-1,$height-1,$grey); 
imageline($image, 0, $height/3, $width, $height/3, $grey);
imageline($image, 0, ($height/3)*2, $width, ($height/3)*2, $grey);
imageline($image, $width/2, 0, $width/2, $height, $grey); 

//Tell the browser what kind of file is come in 
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); 

//Output the newly created image in jpeg format 
ImageJpeg($image);
```

HERE IS EXAMPLE WITH imagettftext() FUNCTION:

```
//Set the image width and height 
$width = 150; 
$height = 30;

//Create the image resource 
$image = ImageCreate($width, $height);  

//We are making three colors, white, black and gray 
$white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255); 
$black = ImageColorAllocate($image, 46, 29, 29); 
$grey = ImageColorAllocate($image, 204, 204, 204); 

//Make the background black 
ImageFill($image, 0, 0, $black); 

$font = 'arial.ttf';
$text='Testing';
imagettftext($image, 20, 5, 10, 20, $white, $font, $text);
ImageRectangle($image,0,0,$width-1,$height-1,$grey); 
imageline($image, 0, $height/3, $width, $height/3, $grey);
imageline($image, 0, ($height/3)*2, $width, ($height/3)*2, $grey);
imageline($image, $width/2, 0, $width/2, $height, $grey); 

//Tell the browser what kind of file is come in 
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); 

//Output the newly created image in jpeg format 
ImageJpeg($image);
```