# I can't set the font size

Tags: php

My code:

```
<?php
// Let's sketch an image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, $r, $g, $b);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  $yazi, $text_color);

// With image registration with the name 'esmer.jpg'
imagejpeg($im, 'esmer.jpg');

//Let's free the memory
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

I'm saving the text as an image. I want to increase the size of the text
and save it. How can I do it?

Comment: Will this help: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954652/cant-change-font-size-for-gd-imagestring]

Answer (score -3):

Add this to the `span` tag:

`<span style="color: white; font-size: 20px;">`

It will change your colour and font size.

Comment: Can you explain a little more in detail? sorry  ı am intern. Where exactly should i write this. I'm getting the text from the input